# Why didn't the notification show?

Tags: android, push-notification

The app will post a notification but when you click it, nothing happens.

```
//this is a Notification app
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0x1123;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.other);
        Button bn1 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,OtherActivity.class);
                PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
                Notification notif = new Notification();
                notif.icon = R.drawable.notify;
                notif.tickerText = "启动其他Activity的通知";
                notif.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
                notif.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
                notif.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
                notif.setLatestEventInfo(MainActivity.this,"普通通知","点击查看", pending);
                NotificationManager nfm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                nfm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notif);
            }
        });
        Button bn2 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        bn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                NotificationManager nfm = (NotificationManager)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                nfm.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
            }
        }); 
    }
}
//the OtherActivity.java
package com.myapp.notification;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
public class OtherActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.other)
    }
}

// sure! the xml layout file is no problem */
```

Answer (score 0):

move the  Button bn1 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

and so on, to the onCreateView method